# Definite the with noncountable nouns

Tags: uncountable-nouns

1. During the course of construction, temporary formwork erected by him collapsed.
2. During course of construction, the temporary formwork...
3. During the construction, the temporary formwork...

I have played with "the" for the same sentence. Has the meaning been changed? I believe some of them are actually wrong with "the", can you tell me why "the" shouldn't be used?

Comment: Can't compare partial sentences since you can't tell the context. #1 does not make sense, did you mean "During the course of construction, temporary formwork *erected* by him collapsed."? In this case, it seems to refer to a specific framework (erected by him) so use "the". Unless it happened to more than one due to shoddy work, that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first sentence *might* need another "the", before "formwork". It depends whether *all the formwork he built* collapsed (needs "the") or only *some formwork he built* collapsed (doesn't need "the".)

The second sentence leaves out a needed "the" before "course" (which is a countable noun, even though each construction has only one course). We are speaking of **the** course of **this** construction, not of any other.

The third sentence is acceptable grammatically, but is not idiomatic.  We would say

- "during the construction **of [X],...**  (count noun; this construction, not some other instance)

but

- "during construction,..." (non-count noun)

Lastly, we would not likely say "formwork erected by him".  We would say "formwork [that] he [had] erected" or "formwork [that] he [had] built". But this is just a matter of style, not of grammar.